# Twitter API v2 Error "You currently have Essential access.."

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm trying to create a tweet with twitter API v2 (`npm/twitter-api-v2`). But im getting this Error given below:

```js
ApiResponseError: Request failed with code 403 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve (Twitter code 453)
```

My code

```js
import { TwitterApi } from "twitter-api-v2";
import "dotenv/config";

var client = new TwitterApi({
   appKey: process.env.APP_KEY,
   appSecret: process.env.APP_SECRET,
   accessToken: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
   accessSecret: process.env.ACCESS_SECRET,
}); 

client.v1
      .tweet("This tweet was written by a bot")
      .then((val) => {
         console.log(val);
         console.log("success");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
         console.log(err);
      });
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: the solution is in the error message

Comment: You're using the `twitter-api-v2` node package, and then using `client.v1` which calls the v1.1 API, and you don't have access to that. Read the docs for the node library, and the error message - the answer is right there.

Comment: Thanks :) if you post it as anwer, i could mark it as solution

Answer (score -3):

You're using the `twitter-api-v2` node package, and then using `client.v1` which calls the v1.1 API, and you don't have access to that. Read the docs for the node library, and the error message - the answer is right there. You will need to request Elevated access to use that particular set of API calls.

Comment: Is this still applicable?  There is no request form for elevated access that I can find.  There are only options to pay to subscribe to higher tiers of API levels.

Comment: I genuinely have no idea what is going on with that API. I am pretty sure that all of the v1.1 API is gone and elevated access doesn’t exist, but you would have to ask Twitter.